# Messed cells in UICollectionView with flow layout (UICollectionViewFlowLayout)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

I built a `UICollectionView` from code, using a standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with **horizontal scrolling**. In the datasource there are 15 items.

I noticed a strange position for one single `cell` and this is the screenshot that explains it better than a thousand words :-)

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, in the fourth column there is an extra cell that shouldn't be displayed.
So, my questions are:

1) **Why?**

2) **How to solve?**

Please note that when I start to scroll the yellow area, the extra-cell suddenly disappear from there and it's shown as expected; and so are the other cells.

So, really strange...

Comment: May be it's this bug? http://openradar.appspot.com/12580808